# Multiple db transaction in one queue laravel 6.5.0

Tags: laravel

Anyone have experience using laravel job with multiple database transaction in one queue?
does laravel support it.
I have an issue, i have 2 different database connection which is database A and database B, when i dispatch my first job using database A everything is working, all my data insert correctly, but when i dispatch my second job using database B , the transaction does not commit and no data insert at all
i need to restart the worker then it will work again.
im using redis as queue driver.

**Database A Transaction**

```
$valid = true;
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
   //some logic happen here if got error $valid will be false

   //if valid true commit else rollback
   $valid ? DB::commit() : DB::rollback();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $valid = false;
  DB::rollback();
}
```

**Database B Transaction**

```
$valid = true;
DB::beginTransaction('b-connection');
try {
   //some logic happen here if got error $valid will be false

   //if valid true commit else rollback
   $valid ? DB::connection('b-connection')->commit() : DB::connection('b-connection')->rollback();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $valid = false;
  DB::connection('b-connection')->rollback();
}
```

**How I dispatch job**

```
DeliveryOrderJob::dispatch($data)->onConnection('swift')->onQueue('do');
```

Basically both using the same logic, the only different is database connection. Please help.

Comment: this is distributed transaction problem.

Comment: @TsaiKoga can you elaborate more

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand, I thought you want to do two diff transaction in one queue multi level.However, You make two diff job to do two diff transaction, I think your queue will work.

Comment: r u using `php artisan queue:work`? if you run this command, you need to know about that this command will not load your code again after you change it. So if you changed your `b-connection` code, you need to restart the queue command, and it will works

Comment: im using ```horizon``` for this, i already restart the queue, but still the same problem, not errors at all, in ```database A``` all is working, but ```database B``` not commit at all, then i restart my queue then it working, but after i run back ```database A``` then ```database B``` not working again

Comment: try `php artisan work:listen` instead of `php artisan queue:work`, and see is same problem again

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `rollback` function in `try{}`. If that logic will fail or any other error occur then the `catch Exception` will `rollback` it.

```
\DB::connection('b-connection')->beginTransaction();
try {

\DB::connection('b-connection')->commit();
}catch (Exception $e) {
  $valid = false;
  DB::connection('b-connection')->rollback();
}
```

Comment: even i remove the  ```rollback``` function in ```try{}```,  my second job still not commit, i need to restart my queue for it to work.

Comment: Are you getting `true` of `false` in `$valid` variable?

Comment: `catch (Exception $e) {

echo $e->getMessage();`

Comment: im getting it ```true``` in ```$valid``` but it not committed

Comment: i already try to ```$e->getMessage();``` but no errors at all